# How to organize jar files in a libraries folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have a Java Project in Eclipse, and a Java Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse.  In the former, all the jar files are shown individually under the top-level project folder.  In the latter, the jar files are under a Libraries folder and the navigation is more convenient.

**Is it possible to organize them in the same way in the Java Project also? If so, how?**

**Update:** It is the Project Explorer View. For the Java Project, I see: "my_project_name" with the arrow expanded to point downwards, then I see: "package_icon src/main/java" and below that "package_icon src/main/resources" and then 20 jar files one below the other: "jar_icon activation-1.1.jar", ...

For the Java Dynamic Web Project I see: "my_project_name" as above, then I see: "JAX-WS Web Services" (unexpanded), then "Deployment Descriptor" (unexpanded), then "Java Resources" which I have expandeded, so I see the components of it below, of which the first is: "package_icon src/main/java", then below it, "package_icon src/main/resources", then below it **"libraries_icon Libraries" instead of 20 jars**!  I have the option of expanding Libraries if I really need to see the 20 jars.

Comment: What view are you talking about? Package Explorer? Project Explorer? Navigator? Remember that Eclipse has many views that can present projects, so you need to specify which one(s) you're talking about. Posting a screen shot would probably help, too.

Comment: Sorry, it is the Project Explorer view. (edited accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to M Miller's answer (but for Juno), click `Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node` in the dropdown of the Package Explorer window:

[image: Reference Libraries Node execution and result]

I'm using:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
```

Answer (score 4):

The only option I found to make things prettier in Eclipse Kepler is to:

1. In the Project Explorer window there is a down arrow in the upper right corner. Select that and then Customize View.
2. Select 'Libraries from external' and then OK.

Kind of cheesy...

**EDIT:** Of course I had to go and do some more digging...and it looks like I'll have to try [this](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/trunk/cp_container.html) and see how it works.

Comment: +1 too, thanks for your correct answer. i wished i had seen it earlier and also accepted it. at this point @rishimaharaj 's elaboration of your answer will be more useful to people who have the same problem, so i am accepting that one. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this "feature" on Eclipse Juno (latest version), when you have a jar file added to the build path it is not shown as a single file on the project.

Try removing one of the jars from the build path to see if it shows up again.

I couldn't find how to turn it off though.

BTW... the project layout for your "Java Project" is more akin to a "Maven Project", which is a bit more powerful.

Comment: not correct but accepting as a thank you for effort since no other answers have been forthcoming for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You should change into the Package Explorer by Window > show View. It will display all the referenced libraries in a `Referenced Libraries` folder.